# How can i use $variable in limit_rate_after directive?

Tags: nginx

I want to set a variable for `limit_rate_after`.

Are there any way to do this.

Comment: You can't. But you could use `limit_rate_after` in `if` block. If you describe complete problem, there could be more ways to find solution.

Comment: Hi Alexey! the problem is backend server will limit rate after `$amount` of bytes which is given by frontend.

Answer (score 0):

Variables are supported in this directive since nginx version 1.17.0 (released 21 May 2019)

http://nginx.org/en/CHANGES says:

```
Changes with nginx 1.17.0                                        21 May 2019

    *) Feature: variables support in the "limit_rate" and "limit_rate_after"
       directives.
```

See http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#limit_rate_after for docs.